# Programatically accessing elements of a custom view

Tags: java, android

I am using a 3rd party library for an android activity, this library:
https://github.com/pavlospt/CircleView

And I have this implementation in my activity:

```
<com.github.pavlospt.CircleView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/weather_result"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:cv_titleSubtitleSpace="40"
        app:cv_fillColor="@color/white"
        app:cv_strokeColorValue="@color/black"
        app:cv_backgroundColorValue="@color/black"
        app:cv_titleColor="@color/black"
        app:cv_titleSize="50dp"
        app:cv_titleText="30ºC"
        app:cv_subtitleSize="12dp"
        app:cv_subtitleText="clima"
        app:cv_subtitleColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

My problem is that I can´t change programatically the app:cv_titleText="30ºC" attribute.

Could anyone help me? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `setTitleText("Your Text")`.

```
CircleView yourcircleview = (CircleView)findViewById(R.id.yourcircleview);
yourcircleview.setTitleText("Your Text");
```

If you are using a Fragment, you have to use `findViewById` with your `view`.

Like: `CircleView yourcircleview = (CircleView)view.findViewById(R.id.yourcircleview);`

Answer (score 1):

`setTitleText(string)` on your CirleView.

Answer (score 1):

```
    ((CircleView)findViewById((R.id.weather_result))).setTitleText("your text here");
```